# JQuery facebook-like plugin to handle the add/remove of tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autosuggest

i am using the jquery-ui autocomplete feature with multiple values for tags,

The thing is that it doesn't provide the feature to handle the hidden values and display current values as buttons (with the delete button and more usability via keyboard),

I am looking for some plugin just [like this one](http://www.devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/) but that works with jquery and no need of mootols or prototype

Do you know if there is any?

If not i am thinking of implement it mysel, the hidden input and displaying a list with all the options i need, but some JQuery alternative to the plugin on the link will just do it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found [this one](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-tags.html) and [this one](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/) and few more (not so similar to the mentioned in question) all in [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/03/35-best-ajax-jquery-autocomplete-tutorial-plugin-with-examples/&ei=VMl4T5aAN4WYhQfesNyiDQ&usg=AFQjCNF5PO8t_JPDA6FPSOI1KHx4lX0NHg) (weird couldn't find them in google separately)